# over ride a defonce var at the repl

Tags: clojure

How can I over-ride (re-def) a defonce var at the repl?

```
> (defonce moo "MOO")

> moo
>> "MOO"

> (defonce moo "CHANGED MOO")
> nil
> moo
>> "MOO"
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you demonstrated, [`defonce`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defonce) checks to see if the named var already has a value, and if it does, leaves it alone. To change an existing root binding, you can just use a regular [`def`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/def):

```
;; using def or defonce here makes no difference
(defonce moo "MOO")

moo
;=> "MOO"

(def moo "CHANGED MOO")

moo
;=> "CHANGED MOO"
```

Answer (score 2):

i wouldn't redefine `defonce`'d var with `def`, because it always looks like a mistake.. If you do it on purpose (if you really need it for some reason), you would probably want to emphasize it. Like by using `alter-var-root`:

```
user> (defonce a 10)
#'user/a

user> (alter-var-root #'a (constantly 20))
20
```

Comment: You are correct in my opinion, but I'd like to note that both ways are equivalent, so it's purely a stylistic decision.

Comment: agreed, that's why i mentioned the possible error likeness.. as for me, i always try to imagine, how would i read my code in a year, and i would probably think whether it is a mistake or not.. Well, nice comment would probably do the trick )

Comment: Yep, as I said, I agree with you. :)